# How to set the zoomLevel of mapView for displaying complete route on MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, routes

This time, i want to display the route between two locations on mapview. I've used googlemapApi for achieving direction. Fortunately I am able to display the route with blue color over the map. 
The only difficulty is to set the correct zoom level So that i could display complete route in the startup of the map loading on the visible screen-portion.

I was wondering for this solution around the stack overflow But i got confused after reading through several number of answer. Finally i decided to post a question.

Can anybody tell me what is the most convenient method to resolve this issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of its the same, but for the Google static maps api, if you provide it with a route and don't give it a zoom level, then it will do exactly what you want automatically.

Have you tried this?